# Reset a form with the exception of one specific field

Tags: jquery

I want to clear the form `form1` without clearing the textbox `textbox1`. However the below does not work:

```
$('#form1').not("input[type=text]#textbox1").trigger('reset');
```

I could do `.html('')` for each field except for `textbox1`, but I do not want to do that since there will be more fields added to the form and therefore the manitaninability is not good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately the `reset` event occurs on the `form` and affects all form related elements within it. To achieve what you need you could select all your required form elements and set their values manually, eg:

```
$('#form1').find('input, select, textarea').not("#textbox1").val('');
```

The element selectors above should be generic enough to cater for additional fields being added to the form dynamically

Answer (score 2):

You can first save the value on `#textbox1` in a variable, then reset the form normally, and then assign the saved value to `#textbox1`. This saves the hassle of selecting each and every input type and resetting it separately.

```
var value1 = $("input#textbox1").val();
$('#form1').trigger('reset');
$("input#textbox1").val( value1 );
```

Comment: That is a good method but unfortunately it won't work in my case. I am doing Asp.net MVC and I need `textbox1`'s value to pass as a parameter into an action. `value1` in your case is client side, won't be passed